# starfield simulation rendering blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl

How to python debug opengl starfield simulation that drawing a black screen?  The code seems ok, but obviously something is off.  Are there any additional functions such as `glGetError` that can verify variables to assist in debugging?  I believe I have hurdled, coded correctly a `glMapBufferRange` function call.

UPDATE: With excellent support by Rabbid76 the program is now rendering the same as expected results.  Thank you very much!

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Support files: [starfield_support.zip](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt09/starfield_support.zip)

Ported from: [starfield.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/starfield/starfield.cpp)

source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True
sys.path.append("./shared")

from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader
from ktxloader import KTXObject    # location of ktx file format loader
from textoverlay import OVERLAY_
from shader import shader_load, link_from_shaders

from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, \
    m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
    scale, m3dLookAt, normalize

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin, floor
import glm
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

myobject = SBMObject()
ktxobject = KTXObject()
overlay = OVERLAY_()

render_prog = GLuint(0)
star_texture = GLuint(0)
star_vao = GLuint(0)
star_buffer = GLuint(0)

debugcontext=True
errors_only=True 

class UNIFORMS_:
    time=0
    proj_matrix=0

uniforms = UNIFORMS_()

NUM_STARS = 2000

import random
random.seed (0x13371337)

def random_float():
    return random.random()

def checkGLError():
    status = glGetError()
    if status != GL_NO_ERROR:
        raise RuntimeError('gl error %s' % (status,))

@GLDEBUGPROC
def CB_OpenGL_DebugMessage(source, type, id, severity, length, message, userParam):
    msg = message[0:length]
    print('debug:', msg)

class Scene:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global render_prog
        global star_vao
        global star_buffer
        global uniforms
        global star_texture

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        vs = GLuint(0)
        fs = GLuint(0)


        fs_source = '''
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D tex_star;
flat in vec4 starColor;

void main(void)
{
    color = starColor * texture(tex_star, gl_PointCoord);
    //color.r = 1.0;
}
'''

        vs_source = '''
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

uniform float time;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

flat out vec4 starColor;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 newVertex = position;

    newVertex.z += time;
    newVertex.z = fract(newVertex.z);

    float size = (20.0 * newVertex.z * newVertex.z);

    starColor = smoothstep(1.0, 7.0, size) * color;

    newVertex.z = (999.9 * newVertex.z) - 1000.0;
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * newVertex;
    gl_PointSize = size;
}
'''
        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vs, vs_source)
        glCompileShader(vs)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            print( 'compile error:' )
            print( glGetShaderInfoLog(vs) )

        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fs, fs_source)
        glCompileShader(fs)
        if not glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            print( 'compile error:' )
            print( glGetShaderInfoLog(fs) )

        render_prog = glCreateProgram()
        glAttachShader(render_prog, vs)
        glAttachShader(render_prog, fs)
        glLinkProgram(render_prog)
        if not glGetProgramiv(render_prog, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            print( 'link error:' )
            print( glGetProgramInfoLog(render_prog) )

        glDeleteShader(vs)
        glDeleteShader(fs)

        uniforms.time = glGetUniformLocation(render_prog, "time")
        uniforms.proj_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(render_prog, "proj_matrix")

        star_texture = ktxobject.ktx_load("star.ktx")

        glGenVertexArrays(1, star_vao)
        glBindVertexArray(star_vao)

        class star_t:
            position = glm.vec3
            color = glm.vec3

        size_star_t = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float) * 6;      # same as glm.sizeof(glm.vec3) * 2

        glGenBuffers(1, star_buffer)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, star_buffer)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_STARS * size_star_t, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        star = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NUM_STARS * size_star_t, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)

        m = (GLfloat * 6 * NUM_STARS).from_address(star)

        for i in range(0, 1000):

            m[i][0] = (random_float() * 2.0 - 1.0) * 100.0
            m[i][1] = (random_float() * 2.0 - 1.0) * 100.0
            m[i][2] = random_float()
            m[i][3] = 0.8 + random_float() * 0.2
            m[i][4] = 0.8 + random_float() * 0.2
            m[i][5] = 0.8 + random_float() * 0.2

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, size_star_t, None)

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, size_star_t, ctypes.c_void_p(glm.sizeof(glm.vec3) )  )
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)


    def display(self):
        global render_prog
        global star_vao
        global uniforms

        currentTime = time.time()

        black = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        one = [ 1.0 ]
        t = currentTime

        proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 1000.0)

        t *= 0.1
        t -= floor(t)

        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one)

        glUseProgram(render_prog)

        glUniform1f(uniforms.time, t)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.proj_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)


        glEnable(GL_BLEND)

        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)


        glBindVertexArray(star_vao)

        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUM_STARS)



        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle
            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):
        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    glutInitContextVersion(4,1)
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Starfield')

    if debugcontext:

        glDebugMessageCallback(CB_OpenGL_DebugMessage, None)

        if errors_only:
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_FALSE)
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_TRUE)
        else:
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_TRUE)

        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)
        glDebugMessageInsert(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_MARKER, 0, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION, -1, "Starting debug messaging service")



    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()
    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)
    scene.init()
    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: Read about [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to python debug opengl [...]

Those days it is common to generate debug output when debugging OpenGL.
The Kronos wiki page [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) tells everything about it what you've to know.

A debug message callback is specified by [`glDebugMessageCallback`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml). The debug output has to be enabled by `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)`. Synchronous outputs can are generated when `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)` is enabled.
Which outputs are generated can be set by [`glDebugMessageControl`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageControl.xhtml) in detail.

To activate the debug output you've to generate a debug call back function with the [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=decorator#grammar-token-decorators) `@GLDEBUGPROC`:

```py
@GLDEBUGPROC
def CB_OpenGL_DebugMessage(source, type, id, severity, length, message, userParam):
    msg = message[0:length]
    print('debug:', msg)
```

Activate the debug callbacks after creating the window:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)
    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Starfield')

    if debugcontext:

        glDebugMessageCallback(CB_OpenGL_DebugMessage, None)

        if errors_only:
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_FALSE)
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_TRUE)
        else:
            glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, None, GL_TRUE)

        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS)
        glDebugMessageInsert(GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_MARKER, 0, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION, -1, "Starting debug messaging service")

    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()
    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)
    scene.init()
    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thank you.

Comment: @StanS. The first thing what I do, when the screen is black, is to change the fragment shader in that way, that the fragment color is not black. e.g. `color = starColor * texture(tex_star, gl_PointCoord) + 0.5;`. The `+ 0.5` adds gray to the output. You can also do something like `color.r = 1.0` in the last line of the shader, which will show a red color on each fragment that is drawn on.

Comment: @StanS. After `ktxobject.ktx_load("star.ktx")` the texture is still bound and that doesn't chang. But there seems to be some issue with the texture. `color = starColor;` shows up something, but `color = starColor * texture(tex_star, gl_PointCoord);` does not.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you.  The simulation now covers the entire window though there are squares.  Perhaps the texture is not loading?

Comment: no effect with `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)` still the squares unfortunately.

Comment: @StanS. The issue is cause becauseyou use a OpenGL compatibility profile context. You've to use a core profile context add `glutInitContextVersion(4, 1)` `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE)` before `glutCreateWindow`. See [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).

Comment: The 4,1 context line won't allow the statement `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)` results in a 1280 invalid enumerant, a search is saying its been deprecated  because starting from OpenGL 3 it only supports point sprites and this was why the enable function was removed. In other words, "The point sprite enum is removed because there's no alternative: all points are point sprites."

Comment: @StanS. Od course you've to remove `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)`. Does it still not work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is still not working.  I have uploading the latest source code I have along with a gif of the current output.  Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: @StanS. In the questions code, you didn't switch back from `color = starColor * texture(tex_star, vec2(0.5));` to `color = starColor * texture(tex_star, gl_PointCoord);`

Comment: OK, I have switched the code back to using `gl_PointCoord` however, the result is now red squares are rendering.  If I remove the added `color.r = 1.0;` a blank screen appears again.

Comment: @StanS. I'm confused, because I've copied the code again and it works fine for me. Probably I have to read the OpenGL specification carefully, to understand what's going on.

Comment: Great work with the debugging code, spot on the spec, I've read the debugging page you've mentioned, and this answer is the nicest python code to debug on the matter, it's spot on.  Consider the question closed, and the answer accepted.  There was a small error in the code, i had `ctypes.c_void_p(2* glm.sizeof(glm.vec3) )` instead of `ctypes.c_void_p(glm.sizeof(glm.vec3) )`  The code is now producing the expected result.  Very nice!

Comment: Good night.  It's 6pm here, I'm about to port the next program.